# get the image of the post

Tags: images, attachments, loop

Im running 'the loop' and I want to get the image of the post (in original size - not thumbnail), how do I do it?

thank you.

Comment: the "Featured Image"? or an image within the post?

Answer (score 2):

The function `the_post_thumbnail()` grabs the featured image for you. You can specify the full size image like this, I think: 
`the_post_thumbnail('full')`

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@Luis:**

WordPress' image handling is tricky, and inconsistent in the edge cases so this may or may not be what you are looking for but I think what you want is this:

```
wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);
```

That will give you the URL of the attached file in it's full size, but if that doesn't give you what you need I'll need you do give me more information about which images you are talking about; Featured, in the Media section, in your posts, etc? Screenshots of your admin where you enter photos will help too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of ways to get_attachments,

```
wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);  

wp_get_attachment_link($id=0, $size='full', $permalink=false, $icon=false);
```

Here is a complete list of `get_attachment` possibilities,
http://digwp.com/2009/08/awesome-image-attachment-recipes-for-wordpress/